# PayPal Form for every 50 quantity get 5 free

Tags: paypal

I am having trouble here with my paypal form. What I am trying to do is set it up so for every 50 in quantity, they get 5 free. Is there away to do this with the discounts?

```
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="9.00">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="CAD">
<input type="hidden" name="discount_amount" value="0" />
<input type="hidden" name="discount_rate" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="discount_num" value="5" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid PayPal Website Payment Standard could not meet your request perfectly. You may have to write some JavaScript to generate the value of discount_amount dynamically.